# Are SQL Virtual Accounts interactive?

Tags: sql-server

Auditors are asking our team to demonstrate whether local virtual accounts (NT SERVICE\SQLWRITER, NT SERVICE\SYSTEM, etc) are interactive or not. I've tried explaining that these accounts were created to run Windows services and we never use them through interactive logon but they would like a demonstration that we cannot physically type a password to logon to these accounts.

We don't disable workstation interactivity for these accounts through GPO so I don't know what else I can do. Has anyone had experience with this question before?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to prove a negative!  Ask your auditors if they can prove that no one could every break into their house.

Or....

ON some box, change the password for one of those accounts to one you know .  Then logoff and try to log on with that account and password.